# Finding the pH among HF and KOH

Tags: acid-base, titration

Okay I ran into this question in homework.

A 100.0 ml sample of 0.20M HF is titrated with 0.10 M KOH. Determine the pH of the solution after adding 200 ml of KOH. The Ka of HF is 3.5 x 10-4?

Oh yeah its multiple choice

- 3.46
- 10.54
- 8.14
- 9.62
- 7.00

I've found answers to similar questions.[Here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091208210458AAQNKyR)

But I come into a different problem with this question. T**he HF and the KOH cancel out each other for they have the same amount of moles**

*I **assume** what ever we're looking at on the other side will have 0.02 moles and is an acid*

- HF -> 0.1L * 0.2M = 0.02 mol
- KOH -> 0.2L * 0.1M = 0.02 mol
- HF-KOH = 0

I beleive this means I can't use the hasselbach equation so I did this:

```
(M of ???) = 0.02 mol / 0.3 L = 0.667*10^(-2) 
3.5*10^(-4) = x^(2) / (0.667*10^(-2))
sqrt(3.5*10^(-4)*(0.667*10^(-2))) = x
```

so there is another way of solving it

I have had some feed back on this reaction: *"You assume the first reaction goes to completion when the Ka is not that high"*

If it doesn't go to completion what do I do?!

I really just need to see how this works out and know why things are happening

Comment: I would recommend you stick to the assumption that the reaction is complete first, before going on to consider the incomplete case. If the reaction is complete, what products are you going to form?

Comment: I'm sorry but I wasn't sure really either FH2 + KO or H2O + FK not really sure actually

Comment: Which of HF and KOH is the base? Which is the acid?

Comment: HF is the acid KOH is the base

Comment: Uhhuh. So the acid is a proton donor right? And the base is a proton acceptor right? What species will they form? Remember KOH exists as $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ in solution.

Comment: So H2O(which is neutral) + FK

Comment: Yes. And as you said, the number of moles of each is equal, so you now essentially have a solution of the weak base, $\ce{F-}$. Calculate the concentration of $\ce{F-}$ and from there calculate the pH.

Comment: I hate stupid questions where you can know too much for your own good.  0.20 m HF is +/- 0.005 molar. The !@#$%^& pH could be "all of the above".

Comment: @orthocresol and what I got for the - log(F-) Which F- should be (0.02 mol / 0.3 L) didn't appear on the answer list and i thought this might have led me to the pOH since we are left with a base. Which didn't show up either. Where does pKa/Ka show up in this solution?

Comment: @MaxW  also what...?

Comment: It has to do with significant figures. In chemistry when we write 0.20 when mean 0.20 +/- 0.005. If the solution were 0.200 molar then that would be +/- 0.0005. Since both the acid and base solution were +/- 0.005 molar, all of the ph values listed could be possible answers. In other words the acid could have been 0.203863859462929428 molar which rounds to 0.20.

Comment: @RyanHenry Please go and look up "pH of a weak base" on SE, or the Internet in general. There is no point in calculating $-\log_{10}[\ce{F-}]$ because that does not correspond to either pH or pOH. Instead, you need to find out how to determine $[\ce{OH-}]$ from $[\ce{F-}]$ and from there you can determine pOH and pH.

Comment: In other words you notion "The HF and the KOH cancel out each other for they have the same amount of moles" is right. Write the balanced chemical equation. What do you have on the right hand side? What happens to the products?

Comment: Okay Thank you all I finally got it. so K is just thrown out the window. and we are left with the equation (F- + H2O <-> FH+ OH-) So i take the Ka to make Kb by (Kw/Ka) and my concentration of F- and OH- was (0.02/0.3) which I plugged into sqrt((Kb)*(M of OH- or F-)) took the -log of that got the pOH and then converted it back to pH (14 - pH) One final thing why did I K out the window does that mean its neutral. Oh and the answers 8.14

Comment: Yes. After balancing the chemical reaction the question is basically "What is the pH of a 0.0667 molar KF solution?"

Comment: @RyanHenry the K+ ions do not affect the pH... at least, probably not enough for you to notice.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> [OP] Okay Thank you all I finally got it. so K is just thrown out the window. and we are left with the equation (F- + H2O <-> FH + OH-) So i take the Ka to make Kb by (Kw/Ka) and my concentration of F- and OH- was (0.02/0.3) which I plugged into sqrt((Kb)*(M of OH- or F-)) took the -log of that got the pOH and then converted it back to pH (14 - pH) One final thing why did I K out the window does that mean its neutral. Oh and the answers 8.14

Paraphrased with paragraphs:

A strong base ($\ce{KOH}$) reacts with a weak acid ($\ce{HF}$) at stoichiometric ratio:

$$\ce{KOH + HF -> H2O + F- + K+}$$

The major species is fluoride, a weak base with pKb = 14 - pKa, where pKa is that of hydrofluoric acid. The potassium ion is a spectator. To find the pH, use your favorite strategy for a pure weak base. The result is pH = 8.14.

As MaxW pointed out in the comments, this relies on getting the stoichiometric ratio just right. If $\ce{KOH}$ is even in slight excess (let's say one tenth of a millimole per liter too much), the pH will be strongly basic (pH 10). If you err in the other direction, you will have an $\ce{HF, F-}$ buffer with an acidic pH.